# How to get the ID of the list item just inserted using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

If I am using JavaScript Client Object Model and [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx) to display a form to enter a new list item, how can I get the ID of that item after its been added?

Example javascript

```
var options = {};
options.url = "/YOUR_SITE/Lists/YOUR_LIST/NewForm.aspx";
options.dialogReturnValueCallback =
           function (dialogResult, returnValue)
              {
                  console.log("dialogResult=" + dialogResult +
                              " returnValue=" + returnValue);
                  // dialogResult will be 1 if saved hit, 0 otherwise
                  // returnValue will be undefined
              }
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to write a CAML query youself and retrieve it. Or use [SPGetLastItemId](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetLastItemId&referringTitle=Documentation) method of SPServices library to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try below code hope it helps you and someone else if needed:

```
function GetInsertedId(PostedTitle,PostedPhone)
{
 var InsertedId= null;
 $().SPServices({
     operation: "UpdateListItems",
     listName: "Results List",
     batchCmd: "New",
     async: false,
    valuepairs: [["Title", PostedTitle],["Phone", PostedPhone]
   ],
   completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
       var CreatedId= 
       $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").attr("ows_ID");
        InsertedId= CreatedId;
    } 
  });
  return InsertedId; 
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be worth a try.

Insert the list item using the [SPListItem.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470423.aspx) method?

This method, creates an item but requires the `SPListItem.Update` method to actually add the item to the list. In between, I suppose you would be able to get the Id of the list item.

Your code block would look something similar to this -

```
     using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.GetList("/lists/announcements");
                SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;

                SPListItem item = items.Add();
                \\Retrieve the Id from the item object and do the manipulations required.
                item.Update();
             }
         }
```

Comment: That won't work for 3 reasons. a) Thats standard object model code, not client object model/javascript. b) The ID isn't actually set until .Update is called. c) I need to use the standard NewForm.aspx to let the user enter the info and using this I would have to create my own form. Thanks though!